# extjs creating classes that make panel forms

Tags: forms, class, extjs

Hi everyone I'm brand new to extjs and new to javascript as well. I'm trying. What I want to do is have a class with a method that makes a panel form with various properties, I want to be able to make clone panel forms whenever I want my calling myclass.makepanel. Why would I want to do that?  I'm just learning different things and getting familiar with extjs, i'm not trying accomplish anything specifically this is my code so far

```
Ext.define('ryan', {

    constructor: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            bodyStyle: {
                "background-color": "green"
            },
            name: 'mypanel',
            title: 'Animal sanctuary, one animal per location  ',
            width: 300,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            test: 'mycat',
            style: 'background-color: #Fdd;',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            items: [{
                id: 'button1',
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'click the button',
                handler: function () {
                    alert('(<^_^>)')
                }
            }, {
                id: 'wildAnimal',
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'animal:',
                name: 'myanimal'
            }, { //end text field
                id: 'myCombo',
                xtype: 'combo',
                fieldLabel: 'choose your animal',
                store: animals,
                queryMode: 'local',
                displayField: 'name',
                listeners: {
                    'change': function (field, selectedValue) {
                        Ext.getCmp('wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);
                    }
                }
            } // end combo

                   ], //end items



        }); // end .create
    } // end ffunc
}); //end ryan

var animals = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
    data: [{
        "id": 'mycat',
        "name": "mycat"
    }, {
        'id': 'mydog',
        "name": "mydog"
    }, {
        'id': 'sbBarGirls',
        "name": "BarGirls-when-drunk"
    }]
}); //end animals.create  // up to here no problems

Ext.onReady(ryan.constructor()); // can't actually display the panel.
```

My apologies the format  doesn't copy directly from my text editor. so if my code is hard to read I can post again. I can put everything in a .onReady instead of trying to define 'ryan' but I don't wanna do that because I want to be able to just make  clone forms whenever by calling the class.

Comment: This class doesn't make sense, it should be extending `Ext.form.Panel`  and configuring it in `initComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a class, but never create an object from it:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var a = new ryan();
});
```

And you don't have to call explicitly the constructor method.

Alternatively with [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-create):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var a = Ext.create('ryan');
});
```

Comment: When I do this and I create multiple objects, var a and var b... the forms come out really screwed up ... do i need to specify locations on the page for each form? is this because I am using ext.getcmp with my listener?

Comment: You can't use id - id of a object should be unambiguous. That means you have to remove the id properties from your form panel items. Use `itemId` instead. For example: `itemId:'wildAnymal'` and then you can call it with: `this.up('form').down('#wildAnimal').setValue(selectedValue);` in your listener

Comment: I also found out that you use queryById instead of .down and can get rid of the hash tag. Thanks for your help :D